# How to determine a path is a file or directory in vb6?

Tags: vb6, filesystems

I'm working on a project that I need to get a path from the user and do sort of things on that path but I need to know what that path is. I can't do this by checking the extension. Because maybe a file doesn't have extensions. Is there any functions like `is_dir()` & `is_file()` functions in php?

Comment: io.file.exists() and io.directory.exists()

Comment: Does it need a reference to add?

Comment: VB6 or VB.NET?  It *does* matter

Comment: Of Course VB6. I can Handle It In VB.NET

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if the original string is a valid string too.

```
Function FileOrFolder(strg As String)
  Dim fs, FExists, DirExists
  Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
  FExists = fs.FileExists(strg)
  DirExists = fs.folderexists(strg)
  If FExists = True Then
    FileOrFolder = "It's a file"                 '// file
  ElseIf DirExists = True Then
    FileOrFolder = "It's a folder"               '// folder
  Else
    FileOrFolder = "Neither a file nor a folder" '// user string invalid
  End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 7):

Have you considerd the obvious?

```
If GetAttr(Path) And vbDirectory Then
    MsgBox "Directory"
Else
    MsgBox "Not directory"
End If
```

Comment: Plus one. Worth mentioning that it will raise an error if the Path does not exist.

Comment: `(GetAttr(Path) And vbDirectory) <> 0` is more explicit

Answer (score 1):

one more function to use : `Dir$()`

With the default `vbNormal` attributes argument `Dir$()` returns an empty string if the pathname argument is a directory

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()
  Dim strPath As String
  Dim strFile As String
  strPath = "c:\temp"
  strFile = "c:\temp\pic.bmp"
  Print strPath & " : " & CStr(IsDir(strPath))
  Print strFile & " : " & CStr(IsDir(strFile))
End Sub

Private Function IsDir(strPath As String) As Boolean
  If Len(Dir$(strPath, vbNormal)) = 0 Then
    IsDir = True
  Else
    IsDir = False
  End If
End Function
```